# How to integrate with google Calendar?

Tags: java, google-calendar-api

I am new to java. I need to integrate with google calendar form my java allpication.But it gives the Exception message : Error connecting with login URI.I use the following code for connect with google.

```
CalendarService myService = new CalendarService("CalendarService"); 
myService.setUserCredentials("calendar.test@gmail.com", "Kdfdfderekra"); 
URL feedUrl = new URL("http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/default/allcalendars/full"); 
CalendarFeed resultFeed = myService.getFeed(feedUrl, CalendarFeed.class); 
System.out.println("Your calendars:"); 
for (int i = 0; i < resultFeed.getEntries().size(); i++) { 
  CalendarEntry entry = resultFeed.getEntries().get(i); 
  System.out.println("\t" + entry.getTitle().getPlainText()); 
}
```

Comment: does the http redirect to an https ? check from the browser ? then you need to target another url?

Comment: yes it redirect to https.Then how to get connect with google ?

Answer (score 1):

Use `new URL("https://...")` instead of `new URL ("http://...")` as shown in the examples in the [Google API documentation](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v2/developers_guide_java#RetrievingEvents).